# How to change hook href with react i18n?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I want to change the origin of the file that is being downloaded when switched between languages, but you need to use a hook for that in React. How can I change between the two hooks using i18n?

JSX file:

```
import { t } from 'i18next'
import React from 'react'
import CVeng from '../../img/CVeng.pdf'
import CVnl from '../../img/CVnl.pdf'

const CTA = () => {
  return (
    <div className="cta">
        <a href={CVeng} download className='btn'>Download CV</a>
        <a href="#contact" className='btn btn-primary'>{t('lets-talk')}</a>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default CTA
```

i18n file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { useTranslation, initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(detector)
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          "lets-talk": "Let's Talk",
          "cv": "{CVeng}"
        }
      },
      nl: {
        translation: {
          "lets-talk": "Contacteer Me",
          "cv": "{CVnl}"
        }
      }
    },
    fallbackLng: "en",

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return <h2>{t('Welcome to React')}</h2>;
}

export default i18n;
```

Comment: Hello, has this been resolved?

Comment: @henry Yes, this has been resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If the answer below solved the issue make sure to mark it as accepted and consider upvoting if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the translation `t` function to get the URI of the CV file (the same way you translate "lets-talk").

Before that though you need to update the way you define the i18n instance. Instead of setting the values of the "cv" keys to, for example, `"{CVeng}"`, you need to set the value to the actual file path value, like this:

```
import CVeng from '../../img/CVeng.pdf'

i18n
  // ...
  .init({
    resources: {
      en: {
        cv: CVeng,
  // ...
```

Then just update your `<CTA>` component to translate the filepath for the CV file (and also update to use `t` from the `useTranslation` hook). Like this:

```
const CTA = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div className="cta">
        <a href={t('cv')} download className='btn'>Download CV</a>
        <a href="#contact" className='btn btn-primary'>{t('lets-talk')}</a>
    </div>
    
  )
}
```